# Adding new line within a textarea that's using asp.net razor markup

Tags: razor, foreach, textarea, newline, viewdata

How do I add a newline after each item, in a textarea that's inside a Razor `@foreach` statement?

The code below displays everything on one line like...

12341524345634567654354487546765

When I want...

12341524

34563456

76543544

87546765

```
<textarea>
    @foreach (var item in ViewData.Model)
    {
                @item["ACCT_ID"]
    }
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add raw HTML with the HTML helper `@Html.Raw()`.  In your case, something like this should work:

```
<textarea>
    @foreach (var item in ViewData.Model)
    {
        @item["ACCT_ID"]
        @Html.Raw("\n")
    }
</textarea>
```

This will insert a raw newline character (`\n`) after each item.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dan. Unfortunately, when I added the '@Html.Raw("<br />") ' , it literally added the syntax <br /> in the output text area.

Comment: My bad, you should use `\n` instead of `<br />` inside a `textarea` tag.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: That worked! I also just found you can use You could use @: to escape as well as <text> . But I think I like your way better. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller:

Simply escape the newline, \n, character in your string.

```
message = "Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint" + "\\n";
message += "Customer " + Customer.ToString() + "\\n";
message += "Invoice " + Invoice.ToString();

Viewbag.AlertMessage = message;
```

In your View:

```
@if (ViewBag.Alertmessage != null)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
           alert("@ViewBag.Alertmessage");
        ViewBag.AlertMessage = "";
    </script>
}
```